# How to solve this system of 3 equations with 3 variables?

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, computer-science, numerical-linear-algebra

I stumbled upon this system with constants $a_{i,j}>0$ that I want to solve for $x,y,z \in\mathbb{R}$:

\begin{align}
a_{2,1}y+a_{3,1}z=& x(y+z) \\
a_{1,2}x+a_{3,2}z=& y(x+z) \\
a_{1,3}x+a_{2,3}y=& z(x+y)
\end{align}

I would appreciate help on the following questions:

1. To which class of equations does it belong?
2. Is the solution unique (except the trivial solution (0,0,0))?
3. How do I solve it in theory resp. approximate the solution effectively?
4. Can 1-3 be generalized to n instead of 3 dimensions?

**Edit:**

I transformed the system to a matrix equation: Let 
\begin{equation}
A=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & a_{1,2} & a_{1,3} \\
a_{2,1} & 0 & a_{2,3} \\
a_{3,1} & a_{3,2} & 0
\end{pmatrix},
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
B=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
and $\pi=(x,y,z)$.
Then the system is just
\begin{equation}
\langle\pi,\pi B\rangle=\pi A
\end{equation},
where $\langle.,.\rangle$ is the elementwise multiplication of two vectors. I found that with an arbitrary starting vector $\pi_0$, the following sequence should converge to the unique solution $\pi$:
\begin{equation}
\pi_{i+1}:=\frac{\pi_{i}A}{\pi_{i}B},
\end{equation}
where the fraction is again elementwise.

Can anyone help me prove that? I could imagine a connection to the stationary distribution of irreducible Markov Chains, but I am not sure.

Also thankful for references to literature or other posts. Thanks!

Comment: Ahh. (Off topic. Just couldn't resist posting.) Your user name reminds me of one of my (MANY) favorite philosophers!

Comment: I haven't seen this kind of system before, so I can't answer any of your questions other than to say it's not linear. But I can say that (0,0,0) is a solution and since your constants are positive, if two of the variables are 0 the third one must be as well. Suppose $y+z \ne 0$. Solve for x in the first equation, substitute into the other two, simplify, then subtract them, and you should get some constraints on your constants by matching up coefficients.

Comment: Thanks, didn't think about the trivial solution (0,0,0) before. But I still have the intuition that there should be a unique nontrivial one.

Answer (score 1):

this is a good question !

if you transform the matrix to inner product form, this question seems much easier:

\begin{equation}
\langle\pi,\pi B\rangle=\pi A
\end{equation}

you just need to calculate this equation immediately !

if this matrix is symmetry, then $xyz=a_{1}a_{2}a_{3}$

in the general case ,it seems like :

$xyz=a_{2,1}a_{1,3}a_{3,2}-a_{1,2}a_{2,3}a_{3,1}$